# how to get like status of facebook php sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, status

I am making event page on facebook by using facebook php sdk.
 i added fb app to fb page.
 the page was made for fb event.
 i tried some ways. but all failed.
 Now, i will make two pages. 
 one is after clicking like.
 the other is before clicking like. 
 i use this soruce to get userf id.

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

it is to get user id source.
  i want to know to get like status.

how can i get like status about facebook php sdk. 
 please let me know it. ^^ plz

Answer (score 0):

If it is a page tab app the signed request will contained a liked parameter. You can read about it on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs

Comment: With the release of the new SDK, it will be no more available. Check it here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request